# Jquery проверка чекбокса и keydown/keydown

Tags: jquery, checkbox, if, keydown

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему неправильно работает скрипт. При нажатии на клавишу W #test должен становится желтым. Если чекбокс #box активен, то при отпускании клавиши див должен оставаться желтым, а если чекбокс неактивен, тогда при отпускании клавиши W див должен обратно становиться серым. Но почему-то условие не работает как задумано.

```js
if ($("#box").prop("checked") != 'checked') {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    $('#test').removeClass('pressed');
  });
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    $('#test').addClass('pressed');
  };
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#test.pressed {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Stay pressed <input type="checkbox" id="box">
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.prop("checked")` возвращает `true` или `false`. И проверку нужно ставить при срабатывании события `keyup`

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if ($("#box").prop("checked") !== true) {
    $('#test').removeClass('pressed');
  }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    $('#test').addClass('pressed');
  };
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#test.pressed {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Stay pressed
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<div id="test"></div>
```

Другие способы проверки атрибута `checked` в jQuery и то, что они возвращают:

`elem.checked` - true (Boolean)

`$( elem ).prop( "checked" )` - true (Boolean)

`elem.getAttribute( "checked" )` - "checked" (String)

`$( elem ).attr( "checked" )` (1.6) - "checked" (String)

`$( elem ).attr( "checked" )` (1.6.1+)  - "checked" (String)

`$( elem ).attr( "checked" )` (pre-1.6) - true (Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

У вас событие keyup подключается только если на старте чекбокс был выделен.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    $('#test').addClass('pressed');
  };
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (!$("#box").is(":checked")) {
    $('#test').removeClass('pressed');
  }
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#test.pressed {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Stay pressed <input type="checkbox" id="box">
<div id="test"></div>
```